# Get __dirname of main module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writting a NPM package and I need to know, within this package, what is the `__dirname` value of the main module.

By "main module", I mean the module that isn't a dependency.

example:

```
a-project
├─ index.js <--- main module
├─ node_modules
│  ├─ my-package <--- can be a symlink
┊  ┊  └─ index.js <--- I'm here
```

I tried 2 things:

try 1 (using the current `__dirname`):

```js
const path = require('path');
console.log(`${__dirname}${path.sep}..${path.sep}..`);
```

```js
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..'));
```

-> doesn't work if the package isn't in `node_modules` but symlinked in `node_modules` (some packages manager like pnpm do this)

try 2 (using `process.argv[1]`):

```js
const escapeStringRegexp = require('escape-string-regexp');
const path = require('path');
const escapedPathSep = escapeStringRegexp(path.sep);

console.log(process.argv[1].match(new RegExp(`^(.*)${escapedPathSep}.*$`))[1]);
```

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.dirname(process.argv[1]));
```

-> doesn't work in production when the main module is lauched by pm2 because `process.argv[1]` become the location of pm2

I though to use [callsite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsite) but I think that it will not work if the package isn't a direct dependency of the main module.

Comment: Try `require('path').dirname(module.main.filename)`

Comment: `module.main` is undefined

Comment: A typo. I mean `require.main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __dirname of main module can be found as follow:

```js
require('path').dirname(require.main.filename);
```

Since [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/u/351705/) posted a comment and not an answer, I post his response here so I can mark the question as resolved.